# jquery next button not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am making a quiz web app for fun. It is only written in JavaScript, html, and css, so there is no server side. Do not tell me that my users can cheat. I know that. I want the next button to work. Right now, the next and previous both do the next action, but it won't work. It can be tried out at http://jsfiddle.net/nimsson/5fW2Z/1/. Once again, I DO NOT care about cheating at this point.

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Quiz Test</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="quiz.css" />
</head>

<body>
    <ul class="quiz">
        <li>
            <div class="quizitem">
                <div class="question">What is 2+2?</div>
                <br />
                <ul class="answers">
                   <li class="wrong answer">a. 5</li>
                   <li class="wrong answer">b. 2</li>
                   <li class="correct answer">c. 4</li>
                </ul>
                <br />
                <br />
                <div class="nav"><span>Previous</span><span>Next</span></div>
            </div> 
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="quizitem">
                <div class="question">What is 2+2?</div>
                <br />
                <ul class="answers">
                   <li class="wrong answer">a. 5</li>
                   <li class="wrong answer">b. 2           </li>
                   <li class="correct answer">c. 4</li>
                </ul>
                <br />
                <br />
                <div class="nav"><span>Previous</span><span>Next</span></div>
            </div> 
        </li>
    </ul>

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="quiz.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

quiz.js:

```
// JavaScript Document
var questionI = 1;

$("ul.quiz div.quizitem ul.answers li.answer").click(function(e) {
    $(this).parent().children().removeClass("selected");
    $(this).addClass("selected");
});
$("ul.quiz div.quizitem div.nav span").click(function(e) {
    var ind = $(this).parent().parent().parent().index();
    $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().hide();
    $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().next().show();
});

$("ul.quiz div.quizitem").hide();
$("ul.quiz div.quizitem").eq(0).show();
```

quiz.css:

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

ul.quiz {
    list-style:none;
    position:relative;
    left:-20px;
}

div.quizitem {
    padding:10px;
    border:1px solid black;
}
div.quizitem:after {
    content: '';
    display: table; 
    clear: both;
}
div.quizitem ul.answers {
    list-style:none;
    position:relative;
    left:-10px;
}
div.quizitem ul.answers > li.answer {
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: #0F6;
    -webkit-transition: all .25s ease;
    -moz-transition: all .25s ease;
    -ms-transition: all .25s ease;
    -o-transition: all .25s ease;
    transition: all .25s ease;
    }
ul.quiz div.quizitem ul.answers > li.answer.selected {
    background-color: #0CF;
}
ul.quiz div.quizitem ul.answers > li.answer:hover {
    background-color: #0F9;
}
ul.quiz div.quizitem ul.answers > li.answer.selected:hover {
    background-color: #0DF;
}
ul.quiz div.quizitem div.nav > span {
    width:100px;
    height:20px;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #0CF;
    -webkit-transition: all .25s ease;
    -moz-transition: all .25s ease;
    -ms-transition: all .25s ease;
    -o-transition: all .25s ease;
    transition: all .25s ease;
    text-align:center;
}
ul.quiz div.quizitem div.nav > span:nth-child(1) {
    float:left;
}

ul.quiz div.quizitem div.nav > span:nth-child(2) {
    float:right;
}
ul.quiz div.quizitem div.nav > span:hover {
    background-color: #0DF;
}
```

Comment: I don't have the time to look through all of the code but your jQuery is a little loud.  Why don't you put a class on the elements you want to target and use those instead of .parent().parent().parent().parent() - it'll be a lot easier to debug the more specific you are.

Comment: @VtoCorleone I will have more that one of that class, and I want individuals. I guess I could use id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going up one too many levels in your `parent()` steps when you hide and show. Also, you're hiding and showing the wrong elements -- when the quiz starts, you hide the `div.quizitem`, but you're targeting the `li` when you hide and show. It's simpler to use `closest()` to find the ancestor you care about, since it has a class you can search for.

```
$("ul.quiz div.quizitem div.nav span").click(function (e) {
    var ind = $(this).parent().parent().parent().index();
    $(this).closest('div.quizitem').hide()
        .parent().next().find('div.quizitem').show();
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/5fW2Z/7/)